# how can i change workspace path to specific folder to build through Jenkins file instead of UI

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have to create build from specific folder of my repository not from the default workspace.
i do not have permission of jenkins UI to modify path over there all i have jenkins file.

Comment: After checkout CD to that specific folder and do your job inside.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply ,: but i tried this  ( sh "cd $workspace/ui" ).

Comment: You do not need $workspace, cause after checkout it is in root of repo, so what you need is sh “cd ui; your_command_to_execute”

Comment: Thanks for your reply .... what has worked out for me is following :-               
                                                                                 dir("${workspace}/ui")

Comment: Good thanks for sharing info